# How do I Bounce only part of a project in Logic Pro?

Tags: logic

In Logic Pro X, I wish to export only part of a project (I'm not yet happy with the end, but I don't want to remove the WIP).

I selected the zone I want with the yellow bar at the top, and pressed "Bounce selected region", but it doesn't seem to do what I want, which is only export the first 22 measures.

What is the proper procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid. I seem to have misclicked because the proper procedure is exactly what I thought I did: select the part you want in the bar (highlight in yellow), Bounce (CMD+B) "project or section", and make sure the "end" is the measure I wanted.

Well, now it works ^^